# meteor autoform required validation not working with nested schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Below is my nested schema. `name.first` is required. but when I submit the form it not validating, it allows empty string. did I missed anything? or How to fix this issue?

```
    Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
      'name.first': {
        type: String,
        max: 50,
        label: "First name"
      },
      'name.last': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        max: 50,
        label: "Last name"
      }
    });

    Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
     profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
      },
    });

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

form:

```
{{#autoForm id="profile" type="method-update" meteormethod="updateProfile" schema=userSchema doc=currentUser collection=Users}}
        {{> afQuickField name="profile.name.first" autofocus='' formgroup-class="col-xs-6"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="profile.name.last" formgroup-class="col-xs-6"}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: Your schema and form look correct. I copy/pasted it in a small project and it works as expected. Clearing the firstname field shows message 'First name is required'. Is the profile.name.first field really empty is you check it in mongoDB? And you have a templatehelper `Users` that returns Meteor.users right?

Comment: Thanks @JosHarink. I made a mistake in  `Users` templatehelper.  THANKS a lot

Comment: @JosHarink Have you tried to submit without entering any data?

Comment: No, I sticked to your question, checked whether the schema validated and that's it. And I made a fake `updateProfile` method. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your schema
Schema is looking good but you will have add object for the name.

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
  'name': {
   type: Object,
   optional: false
  },
  'name.first': {
    type: String,
    max: 50,
    label: "First name"
  },
  'name.last': {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    max: 50,
    label: "Last name"
  }
});
```